# Optimizing TF slow ops: how to find the tensorflow op that slows down the model with tensorflow profiler

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

My model runs very slowly, So I tried the TF [profiler](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/profiler/Profiler). Now given the outputs, I'm having a hard time pinning down the place where `Sub` and `AssignSub` are created with the Python API and understanding why they are using so much CPU time. Any help is much appreciated! Thank you in advance.

The `profiler.advise()` outputs the following

`ExpensiveOperationChecker:
top 1 operation type: Sub, cpu: 949.78ms, accelerator: 41.98ms, total: 994.15ms (17.51%)
top 2 operation type: AssignSub, cpu: 578.64ms, accelerator: 26.61ms, total: 606.63ms (10.69%)
top 3 operation type: Conv2D, cpu: 173.67ms, accelerator: 214.06ms, total: 388.10ms (6.84%)
top 1 graph node: gradients, cpu: 0us, accelerator: 0us, total: 0us
top 2 graph node: densenet121_6, cpu: 0us, accelerator: 0us, total: 0us
top 3 graph node: densenet121_4, cpu: 0us, accelerator: 0us, total: 0us
model_local_global.py:939:<module>, cpu: 3.93sec, accelerator: 1.06sec, total: 5.00sec
model_local_global.py:939:<module> (gradient), cpu: 149.26ms, accelerator: 298.11ms, total: 447.78ms`

Comment: Go in and add `name=` to all your operations, in particular, the assign and subtract operations. It should be obvious once you have a unique name attached to them. Using things like the profiler, debugger, or tensorboard without good naming of ops is truely maddening. :)